# apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.2 with jsf results in java.lang.LinkageError

Tags: jsf-2, tomee-7

I try to setup a minimal jsf project with tomee `apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.2`

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.peterspace</groupId>
    <artifactId>swarm</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>swarm Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>swarm</finalName>
        <!-- Use Java 1.7 -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Demo for jee servlet hello world config</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

when starting the server i get an exception

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/tomee/catalina/TomEEWebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/faces/context/ExternalContext"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2268)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEWebConfigProvider.getFacesServletMappings(TomEEWebConfigProvider.java:36)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:154)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

when i add a faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

the error changes

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/tomee/catalina/TomEEWebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/faces/context/ExternalContext"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2268)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:811)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1254)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEEWebappClassLoader.loadClass(TomEEWebappClassLoader.java:179)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.apache.tomee.myfaces.TomEEWebConfigProvider.getFacesServletMappings(TomEEWebConfigProvider.java:36)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer.initFaces(AbstractFacesInitializer.java:154)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener.contextInitialized(StartupServletContextListener.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

whats wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 4):

got it, i just forgot the `<scope>provided</scope>` for my dependency

Comment: btw, sometimes eclipse blocks deployment to glassfish, when provided is missing